# Django Override Admin App with custom data per group

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i have an app for manage the configuration in my django web-app (some user can change the configurations).
Now i'm trying to show only the configuration that the user can change (based on groups) and not all the configuration available in my app.

I want to change the following part of the django admin and show only the configuration that the user can change.

[image]

Example for the user "Admin" i want to show all the configuration available in the app, but for the user "User1" (group = "group1") i want to show few setting.

Is there any method to override this part of the django app?

Comment: what? what do you want? it's unclear

Comment: Sorry, i sent the question for error, added more infos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a groups field in your question model `groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)` and then you can override `get_serch_results` in ModelAdmin:

Example:

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('question','otherfield')

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super().get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        filtered_by_group = queryset.filter(groups__in=request.user.groups.all())
        return filtered_by_group, use_distinct


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```